# Why does my listbox show

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

Using the following,

```
DataTable Customers = GetAllCustomers();
lbCustomers.DataSource = Customers;
listBox1.DisplayMember = "firstName";
listBox1.ValueMember = "phoneNumber";
```

I am getting a listbox full of `System.Data.DataRowView`  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `lbCustomers` and `listBox1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't this should be

```
DataTable Customers = GetAllCustomers();
lbCustomers.DataSource = Customers;
lbCustomers.DisplayMember = "firstName";
lbCustomers.ValueMember = "phoneNumber";
```

Comment: I had a second list box, forgot to name it properly, and overlooked that I was using it in this spot. Obvious once it was pointed out.  Thanks.